# Launching a node two times with same namespace

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to generate left and right images from 2 webcameras. The two images generated topics are then passed to stereo image proc package for disparity and point cloud generation. However for this the namespace of left and right images should be same. The launch file is https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5TBCZ9AVMFvOVdxT1N5ODNZNkE . I want the images on topics like /camera/left/image_raw and /camera/right/image_raw however the topics now are  /camera1/left/image_raw and /camera2/right/image_raw
Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit**

@huanxiner, I got an error

```
roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/camera/image_view]. Please check all <node> 'name' attributes to make sure they are unique. Also check that $(anon id) use different ids. The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270958/launching-a-node-two-times-with-same-namespace/) by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-09-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [huanxiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28265/huanxiner/) on 2017-09-15**:
Why don't you just put the two nodes in the same group?

```
 <group ns="camera">
     ...
 </group>
```

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-15**:
@BotLover: could you please post your launch file here so if it gets removed from your Drive we still have it? Thanks.

**Comment by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on 2017-09-15**:
@huanxiner, I got an error **roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/camera/image_view].
Please check all  'name' attributes to make sure they are unique.
Also check that $(anon id) use different ids.
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file**

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-15**:
@BotLover: I updated your question with error from your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is some redundancy in your launch file. How about that?

```
<launch>
 <group ns="camera">
  <node name="left" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="image_view_left" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/left/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
  <node name="right" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video2" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="image_view_right" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/right/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>  
 </group>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on 2017-09-15**:
Yes, I tried with this but I got an error stating
**roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/camera/image_view].
Please check all  'name' attributes to make sure they are unique.
Also check that $(anon id) use different ids.
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file**

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-15**:
@BotLover: make sure every node has a unique name. I.e., change the `name` attribute to be different for every `<node>` tag.

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2017-09-15**:
Have you replaced your launch file with my *complete* code example? Have you noticed, that I changed the names of the "image_view" nodes to "image_view_left" and "image_view_right"?

**Comment by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on 2017-09-15**:
Wow!!!!!
@Andre it works. Can you please explain me the reason for future references?

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2017-09-15**:
You are welcome. Every node you are running in your ROS environment has to have a unique name. You will have to take care of this, especially if you want to run multiple nodes of the same type. Please see #q61983 for an explanation on the difference between node types and node names.

**Comment by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on 2017-09-15**:
Thank you so much!